# Hyphen in edge N-gram for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, n-gram

I need to made an autocompletion in text which contain french words with hyphen like "e-commerce".

So I use the edge_ngram to tokenize my words.

But when I search "e-comme" the tokenizer split my search in two words. And because I set the "min_gram" to 3 the token "e" is removed.

So I get theses tokens :

```
{
"tokens": [
    {
        "token": "com",
        "start_offset": 3,
        "end_offset": 6,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": "comm",
        "start_offset": 3,
        "end_offset": 7,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 1
    },
    {
        "token": "comme",
        "start_offset": 3,
        "end_offset": 8,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 2
    }
]
```

}

Is there anyway to say to the tokenizer to not split words on hyphen ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include the mapping configuration. According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html), per default the `edge_ngram` would count all characters as "in-token", so I suspect you have a non-default `token_chars` configuration.